# What is the relation between bond energy and stability?

Tags: bond, energy

My book has two confusing statements about bond energy:

> The most stable bond is the bond with the highest bond energy.

> A system with low energy is a stable system. Thus, a bond is formed when electron energy level is the lowest.

So, does high energy means more stability or less stability?

Comment: Bond energy is shows how much _lower_ is energy of the compound.

Comment: “Bond energy” is the same as bond dissociation energy — the amount of energy to break the bond.
So, if adding all the 'bond energies' of a molecule gives the highest number, it requires the *most energy to break*, and therefore is the most stable.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it in this way. Consider the energy to break a bond to be arbitrarily assumed to be at $\pu{0 J/mol}$. Now, there are two bonds, $\ce{A-B}$ and $\ce{C-D}$. Let's say they have energies of $\pu{-242 kJ/mol}$ and $\pu{-378 kJ/mol}$. Clearly, the $\ce{C-D}$ bond has the lower energy.

Now, you can say that a stronger bond needs more energy to break it. So, this means that you need to supply $\pu{242 kJ/mol}$ of energy to break $\ce{A-B}$ and $\pu{378 kJ/mol}$ of energy to break $\ce{C-D}$. You can definitely see that $\ce{C-D}$ needs more energy to break it, and to bring the energy to $\pu{ 0 J/mol}$.